# Android Studio app says it stopped over and over again

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

Last time I opened the project, it was working but now the app keeps stopping. I didn't even change any code as far as I remember. I can't even open the app now

```
2022-06-07 21:06:18.942 7244-7244/com.example.labactivity01layoutsandactivity E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.labactivity01layoutsandactivity, PID: 7244
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.labactivity01layoutsandactivity/com.example.labactivity01layoutsandactivity.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity com.example.labactivity01layoutsandactivity.MainActivity@661d5fe does not have a NavController set on 2131231012
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity com.example.labactivity01layoutsandactivity.MainActivity@661d5fe does not have a NavController set on 2131231012
    at androidx.navigation.Navigation.findNavController(Navigation.java:61)
    at androidx.navigation.ActivityKt.findNavController(Activity.kt:30)
    at com.example.labactivity01layoutsandactivity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:26)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
```

Comment: Are you using Navigation component in this project?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.